# Authorization Not working with identityserver4 when using docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I have a .net-core web api app that is configured to use identityserver4.

Everything works fine locally.

One of the web api methods contains [Authorize] attribute that works fine when running locally. 
But when using "docker" and calling the api method using postman with Authentication Bearer, i get "500 internal server error".

I have this configuration in my web api for CORS.

```
services.AddCors();

app.UseCors(policy =>
{
    policy.AllowAnyHeader();
    policy.AllowAnyMethod();
    policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had similar problems with docker, in my case the reason was, that the identityserver was not accessible via the same url in the docker environment as in local (notice that "localhost" in the docker container points to the container itself)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer i just figured this one out just now.
Looks like the network connection between the docker and the host machine is different. Again thanks for the answer.

Comment: By the way how did you manage to dockerize the identityserver ? 
i am having an issue with that.

Comment: What do you mean? I just added docker support via vs2017 and adjusted the resulting docker-compose file slightly, so it had a specified port and a hostname. I had to make sure, that the hostname  was the same as the domain it is actually reachable under and then it worked. Then all the applications in your docker compose should be able to auth with the identityserver